# LineSeries.cs not found

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a graph with C# and the WPF chartingToolkit, I have the following code:

```
LineSeries lineSeries1 = new LineSeries();
lineSeries1.Title = region;
lineSeries1.DependentValuePath = "Value";
lineSeries1.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
lineSeries1.ItemsSource = points;
this.Graph.Series.Add(lineSeries1);
```

where `points` is a `Dictionary<string, int>` created in earlier code. This code compiles fine and runs fine until it reaches the line `LineSeries lineSeries1 = new LineSeries();`. Upon reaching this line it throws a `Source Not Found: LineSeries.cs not found` exception. I have tried putting it as `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries lineseries1 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries();` but that failed to fix the issue. Everywhere I look for examples of how to do this it is written exactly how I have it.

EDIT:
It works perfectly without the debugger. The problem only exists with it.

Comment: You say it compiles and runs. Is this under the debugger? Not under the debugger?

Comment: with the debugger. Sorry it works without the debugger I will edit that part into the OP

Comment: So is it simply that you're attempting to "Step into" library code? If so, just "Step over" instead.

Comment: It's not the same page that you get when doing that. And it still throws it whether you are stepping though or not. It only fixes it to find the `release` exe and run it without VS

Comment: In which case, does [this MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0873999-a7ab-4638-9590-ebd3890d4bf7/wpf-toolkit-chart-cant-add-series-from-codebehind?forum=wpf) help at all?

Comment: The part about not requiring matching source files seems to be helping, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger was looking for a source file but was not able to find it. This will have been either because you don't have it available or because the version of the source you have does not exactly match the version which was compiled into your library.

If the latter is the case, you can work around it by going to Tools -> Options -> Debugging and unchecking the "Require source files to exactly match the original version" option.